# Having an issue setting up react google maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am getting multiple errors and have no clue where to go from there.

> Required props containerElement or mapElement is missing. You need to provide both of them.
>
> The `google.maps.Map` instance will be initialized on mapElement and it's wrapped by containerElement.
>   You need to provide both of them since Google Map requires the DOM to have height when initialized.

These are all the errors showing. I looked at the documentation and I know I am probably setting this up wrong, but I don't really know what to do from the documentation.

**Here is the code:**

**GoogleMapPage:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from 'react-google-maps';
const googleMapURL =
  'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.27&libraries=places,geometry&key=AIzaSyA7XEFRxE4Lm28tAh44M_568fCLOP_On3k';

const GettingStartedGoogleMap = withGoogleMap(props =>
  <GoogleMap
    ref={props.onMapLoad}
    defaultZoom={3}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922 }}
    googleMapURL={googleMapURL}
    onClick={props.onMapClick}
  >
    {props.markers.map(marker =>
      <Marker
        {...marker}
        onRightClick={() => props.onMarkerRightClick(marker)}
      />
    )}
  </GoogleMap>
);

class GettingStartedExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <GettingStartedGoogleMap
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default withGoogleMap(GettingStartedExample);
```

**App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import GettingStartedExample from './components/GoogleMapPage';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <GettingStartedExample />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have
`export default withGoogleMap(GettingStartedExample);`

containerElement and mapElement have to be props outside of withGoogleMaps to not throw the error for me. Does it work as:
`export default GettingStartedExample;`